# Can you split a very large sample into smaller ones to get more observations?

Tags: sampling, sample-size, treatment-effect

Suppose you are running an experiment on the entire population of the US. Every day you alternate giving them some treatment and you observe some index at an aggregate, country level. Note that for this experiment **we only care about the results for the country as a whole**.

So an example would be:

| Day | Treatment | Index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 5.2 |
| 2 | 1 | 6.1 |
| 3 | 0 | 6.2 |
| 4 | 1 | 6.0 |
| ... | ... | ... |

It's obviously very expensive to give this treatment to 300M+ people so you want to minimize the number of times you have to do this. You realize that the US is very large so you decide that you will do this same scheme, giving the treatment to everyone, but when you *measure* the index, instead of doing it at the country level, every day you randomly split the population into 300 groups of 1M (or whatever split is reasonable) and measure their index. Now, with the justification that 1M randomly sampled people should be representative of the overall population, we've managed to magically turn 1 observation into 300. And so now we can probably afford to just run it for a couple days and get a reasonable estimate of the treatment effect.

**Note:** *You have to give the treatment to everyone on each day. Giving it to only 1M people each day would be way more cost-effective and the normal thing to do but that's not the question.*

**Question 1**

If our model assumes that there are no temporal effects and the index only depends on the treatment, is this a reasonable thing to do? I would say yes if the groups are large enough or if we can control for the demographics of each group in our model.

**Question 2**

If there are temporal effects (let's say day of week for this) is this reasonable? I would say no because even if you control for day of week in your model, you still want adequate exposure to *different* Mondays and Tuesdays etc. to make sure you capture the effect since each could be different. In this case you'd still need to run the treatment for a number of weeks. But would we potentially need to run it for a shorter period? Again I think no since the added samples on a single day doesn't add information about the day of week effects.

Comment: The table shows correctly for me when in edit mode and looks like garbled text to me in the question... Hopefully it looks nice to you.

Comment: This is what we do with statistics *every time*, you never have the luxury to look at the whole population, so you always operate on a sample. I'm not sure what is your question here?